# How can I use GitHub secrets in a .npmrc file?

Tags: npm, github-actions, .npmrc, github-secret

I have a project on GitHub that has several dependencies all of which are published on GitHub Package Registry.

I use GitHub actions to publish my packages. I am able to use GitHub secrets in my `workflow.yml` file but not so in my `.npmrc` file.

As there is no way for a CI environment to know the value stored in a secret if I used it in my `.npmrc` file as `_authToken={GPR_TOKEN}`, I am curious if there is a workaround since my current implementation is to use my Personal Access Token(PAT) literally in my npmrc.

I have used `${GITHUB_TOKEN}` successfully but it fails during my CI job because `{GITHUB_TOKEN}` is only scoped for the repository the workflow is running from and cannot be used to install dependencies.

I also tried using `_authToken={MY_PAT_SECRET}` in the `.npmrc` file but my CI job fails. The only thing that has worked so far is pasting my PAT in `.npmrc` but I don't want to do it.

Any ideas or workarounds about how to use GitHub secrets in a .npmrc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not the ideal solution, but you can achieve the result you want by using a `sed` command.

Supposing your `.npmrc` file looks like this:

```
authToken=MY_PAT_SECRET
```

You could replace the `MY_PAT_SECRET` by the PAT secret value in the pipeline by doing a step like this (after having previously used the `actions/checkout`):

```
     - name: Replace values
       shell: bash
       env: 
          PAT: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
       run: |
         sed -i.back "s|MY_PAT_SECRET|${PAT}|g" ./path/to/.npmrc
```

*Note 1: This will work on a ubuntu or macos runner.*

*Note 2: The `sed` command will update all instance with the specified syntax, so don't use something too generic.*

---

I made a test in this [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/4366284597/jobs/7636080142) by using this [workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester76.yml). And it worked as expected:

[image]

Comment: Tried this and it did work. Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the reason it won't work other than those runners? In our case this is NOT working within a custom runner. It is replacing values only with the masked string `***`

Comment: What is the custom command OS? The `***` is just the encrypted syntax used by GitHub to not expose sensitive data, if this value appears through an `echo` command in further step, it's probably that you updated the secret value as expected :)

Answer (score 2):

According to https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/npmrc:

> Environment variables can be replaced using `${VARIABLE_NAME}`.

So, if you configure your PAT as an environment variable, it should automatically be replaced. For example, for an env var `${PAT}`, setting `PAT` with the `env` context like this should work:

```yaml
     - name: Build
       env: 
         PAT: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
       run: ...
```

---

If for some reason the above isn't working for you, you can use the [`envsubst`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/envsubst.1.html) command line utility to substitute `PAT` and other env vars.

It works on all GHA-hosted runners under `shell: bash`.

Example:

```yaml
     - name: Set up .npmrc
       env: 
         PAT: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
       run: |
         envsubst < .npmrc > .npmrc.envsubst
         mv .npmrc.envsubst .npmrc
```

It creates an intermediate file that needs to be renamed to the original.

The above will substitute all the available env vars.

If you want to substitute some specific ones only, you need to mention those. Here's an example that only substitutes `PAT` and `AUTHOR`:

```bash
envsubst '${PAT} ${AUTHOR}' < .npmrc > .npmrc.envsubst
mv .npmrc.envsubst .npmrc
```

Comment: this method is no longer working. GHA is not allowing `envsubst` to replace secrets in files

Comment: @Vineeth: Why not? What's the issue/error?

Comment: I'm using `envsubst` to expand variables inside an SQL file and while running it, it seems that the values are not replaced with secret values but only masked string `***`.
Error: `ERROR:  column "***" does not exist`

Comment: @Vineeth: Well, that's specific to your use case. It's not like `envsubst` suddenly stopped working in GHA workflows. Also, `envsubst` substitutes env vars, not secrets (not directly anyways). You should create a new question with all the details of your use case including your workflow, the file you're trying to update, and the respective error logs. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Just found out that the issue is very specific to custom runners in Github Action. This will work with for default github runners.

Comment: @Vineeth: No problem. What was the issue? Technically, it should work wherever `envsubst` is installed. I wonder why it wasn't working for you even if it's a self-hosted runner.

Comment: No clue why isn't it working in self-hosted runners. May be Github is having additional security for self-hosted? 
We followed an untidy method to have the variables expanded in a default runner and copy that file to the self hosted runner where the operations are happening

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use a PAT here. They are for use by humans, not your CI workflow. Instead, as you point out, use the `GITHUB_TOKEN`.

Here is how:

1. In the repo which holds the npm package: Click the name of your package from the front page, right-most column. (section named "Packages").
2. You are now on a page where you can see the versions published for said npm package. Again look in the right-most column. You'll find a link called "Package settings". Click it.
3. Go to the section named "Manage Actions access". Add the repository to which you want to grant access to consume the npm package (or grant access to publish).

Done. You can now use the `GITHUB_TOKEN` instead of the PAT.

And by the way: GitHub's documentation is highly confusing. It says for example that you must use a PAT. This is no longer correct.