# Passing GitHub Actions environment variables to the Kubernetes index file

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions

Is there a way to pass GitHub Actions environment variables to the Kubernetes index file?

The workflow file, this part will get the run number:

```
- name: Taggig
  run: |
    echo "imageTag=${{ github.run_number }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

And I want to pass it to the index like -

Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: my-image:{{ env.imageTag }}
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675348/how-can-i-use-github-secrets-in-a-npmrc-file

Comment: With `image: my-image:$imageTag`, you can use `envsubst`. I've been using `envsubst` to populate k8s manifests for quite some time now without any issues so far.

Comment: @Azeem tried one of the suggestions ( replacing with sed ), worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: Great! You're welcome! BTW, I'd prefer `envsubst` to `sed`. With `sed`, you have to write it explicitly. For one variable, it might not be an issue. But, with multiple variables, it becomes quite cumbersome in the long run. Anyways, you'll figure it out later. ;)

Comment: The tip is really helpful! I had to use sed for 5-10 variables and I already don't feel it pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `envsubst` as Azeem mentioned:

So you would have something like:

```
containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: my-image:$imageTag
```

In your deployment file, then with [`envsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) you would substitute that  `imageTag` environment variable with:

```
envsubst < deployment.yml
```

Supposedly you named your deployment file as `deplyoment.template.yml`, you'd have an something like:

```
steps:
  - name: Taggig
    run: |
      echo "imageTag=${{ github.run_number }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  - name: Render k8s manifests
    run: envsubst < deployment.template.yml > deployment.yml 
  
  - run: kubectl apply -f ./deployment.yml
```

---

One other approach is to use [`kubectl set image`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-image-em-), for example:

```
  - name: Taggig
    run: |
      echo "imageTag=${{ github.run_number }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

  - run: kubectl set image -f deployment.template.yml  my-container=my-image:$imageTag --local -o yaml > deployment.yml 

  - run: kubectl apply -f ./deployment.yml
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`kustomize`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/) or [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) to set your `image:tag` value

Comment: I will try it and provide feedback. I tried with sed as per @Azeem relevant article and it worked fine.

Comment: Hey, I tried the second one with `kubectl set image` and it worked for me **perfectly**! Thank you

Comment: Here's what I do using `envsubst`, if that would help: 

`cat k8s/kustomization.yml | KEY=VALUE envsubst > k8s/kustomization.yaml` and `kustomize build ./k8s > k8s/deployment.yaml` and finally  `kubectl apply -f k8s/kustomization.yaml`