# How to use GitHub Actions secrets in k8s Job env?

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions

I want to deploy a k8s job in k8s cluster with GitHub Actions.
But there are some env variables in `job.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi01
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi01
        image: xx:version
        command: ["node", "schedule/schedule.js"]
        env:
          - name: DB_HOST
            value: {{ ${{ secrets.DB_HOST }} }}
          - name: DB_PORT
            value: {{ ${{ secrets.DB_PORT }} }}
          - name: DB_USER
            value: {{ ${{ secrets.DB_USER }} }}
          - name: DB_PASSWORD
            value: {{ ${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }} }}
```

because those env variables are sensitive, I save them as secrets.

In GitHub Actions workflow, I don't know how to put secrets into env variables of `job.yaml`.

With this command, I don't know which option I should use:

```
kubectl apply -f job.yaml [Options]
```

Could you please provide an example for me to refer?

In workflow, I used this script but I don't know how to input `${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}` into YAML file:

```yaml
- name: Deploy app to AKS
  run: |
    kubectl apply -f job.yaml
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675348/how-can-i-use-github-secrets-in-a-npmrc-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work like that you have to Go with **placeholder** option, add one **step** into your **Github Action**

**Job.yaml**

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi01
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi01
        image: xx:version
        command: ["node", "schedule/schedule.js"]
        env:
          - name: DB_HOST
            value: VAL_DB_HOST
          - name: DB_PORT
            value: VAL_DB_PORT
```

**Run command**

```
sed -i "s,VAL_DB_HOST,$secrets.DB_HOST," job.yaml
sed -i "s,VAL_DB_PORT,$secrets.DB_PORT," job.yaml
```

You can write **shell script** or further **optimize** it as per need. Above command will replace **VAL_DB_HOST** in **Job.yaml** with **environment** variable **value** saved.

Once your file **job.yaml** is ready, apply the changes

```
kubectl apply -f job.yaml
```

You can use the different method, **Helm**, **Skafold** also for **templating** if you are looking for that else above will be simple method.

Comment: it works, thanks for your professional answers.